# Return column value based on a vectors of row.names in a data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, static, quantmod

I have a sample data.frame below (subset of a very large cyclic database)

```
> dput(try)
structure(list(Actuator.Force = c(-402.57388, -400.83463, -402.72595, 
-404.24283, -404.07663, -403.83575, -407.55435, -418.7684, -435.86246, 
-462.38239, -504.09146, -558.40039, -618.46674, -681.58704, -748.87347, 
-814.95032, -880.57739, -946.11627, -1012.9043, -1075.2557, -1141.4972, 
-1209.1968, -1272.8707, -1336.021, -1400.5078, -1465.5786, -1528.6499, 
-1589.5626, -1654.6541, -1717.825, -1780.0903, -1839.9329, -1902.9841, 
-1964.1945, -2025.569, -2085.9578, -2148.239, -2207.5295, -2267.5806, 
-2328.6467, -2388.4958, -2447.5298, -2506.7534, -2567.687, -2625.7661, 
-2682.866, -2741.3511, -2802.1934, -2858.2546, -2915.1028, -2972.7683, 
-3030.8093, -3089.2439, -3145.5701, -3199.8442, -3259.2087, -3315.8582, 
-3371.958, -3426.5596, -3484.3855, -3541.2642, -3595.3362, -3650.0208, 
-3708.3748, -3763.8076, -3820.0623, -3875.3044, -3932.9504, -3989.6238, 
-4047.5957, -4104.8169, -4164.8237, -4223.5444, -4283.3813, -4341.3989, 
-4403.166, -4462.1479, -4522.5728, -4584.0186, -4644.7656, -4704.3525, 
-4762.6826, -4821.8706, -4878.8818, -4924.1021, -4959.0415, -4985.9517, 
-5005.4531, -5017.8027, -5026.0757, -5032.3428, -5036.8042, -5038.9292, 
-5039.5361, -5043.021, -5043.0981, -5043.0415, -5042.627, -5014.4199, 
-4853.5854, -4566.9771, -4198.7612, -3774.5527, -3317.6958, -2847.5229, 
-2364.7585, -1880.9485, -1405.4272, -930.289, -467.04822, -18.867363, 
421.17499, 838.86719, 1239.9121, 1626.0669, 1990.6389, 2334.0852, 
2655.344, 2962.0227, 3243.7817, 3506.2249, 3744.2622, 3959.8271, 
4156.7061, 4324.9048, 4469.229, 4591.6689, 4687.4194, 4764.0801, 
4814.6167, 4840.313, 4846.0181, 4826.3135, 4777.6553, 4696.0791, 
4583.854, 4442.457, 4272.5254, 4076.7224, 3851.1211, 3603.1853, 
3330.7456, 3038.3157, 2724.115, 2386.5476, 2032.5809, 1660.0547, 
1268.0084, 859.16675, 432.4075, -14.131592, -479.29309, -955.67108, 
-1444.614, -1937.2562, -2437.0085, -2941.8914, -3450.9009, -3959.9597, 
-4468.9795, -4981.2549, -5492.6997, -6002.334, -6510.5425, -7016.2432, 
-7517.8286, -8013.1348, -8500.4199, -8974.8867, -9439.5479, -9890.5938, 
-10326.367, -10744.421, -11147.754, -11534.83, -11902.651, -12248.997, 
-12577.919, -12885.458, -13172.309, -13441.554, -13691.502, -13922.634, 
-14127.116, -14305.272, -14458.267, -14582.934, -14685.274, -14758.539, 
-14806.058, -14830.719, -14836.625, -14822.204, -14773.916, -14700.484, 
-14597.968, -14469.834, -14312.099, -14126.422, -13915.136, -13676.505, 
-13412.388, -13120.703, -12807.961, -12473.883, -12115.751, -11740.082, 
-11342.633, -10929.945, -10502.158, -10062.869, -9611.8271, -9146.6006, 
-8673.3545, -8191.7417, -7700.769, -7200.9346, -6695.8809, -6185.2378, 
-5670.8711, -5154.9995, -4643.4414, -4135.0015, -3629.2859, -3125.657, 
-2626.541, -2134.0662, -1646.4242, -1168.816, -699.63068, -245.34488, 
192.7984, 618.76703, 1033.223, 1428.922, 1807.2645, 2165.6274, 
2507.6655, 2826.2754, 3120.4724, 3395.2593, 3647.6946, 3879.4983, 
4086.3855, 4265.1323, 4421.6831, 4554.3594, 4657.8184, 4736.9561, 
4792.6724, 4822.3784, 4830.3091, 4815.9038, 4773.9692, 4706.4736, 
4614.8379, 4491.3198, 4337.8892, 4158.002, 3949.3147, 3713.4622, 
3453.9114, 3167.8179, 2861.2598, 2536.3259, 2187.3623, 1822.752, 
1437.5449, 1034.8208, 617.23962, 183.35637, -270.79733, -738.95618, 
-1220.1345, -1710.7787, -2206.1941, -2706.4871, -3210.8625, -3721.0002, 
-4233.6387, -4747.7271, -5258.7578, -5771.3071, -6280.7759, -6791.0166, 
-7295.0229, -7794.4199, -8287.4189, -8771.6377, -9243.3457, -9702.2559, 
-10146.865, -10577.053, -10989.863, -11385.981, -11760.477, -12116.938, 
-12456.351, -12772.688, -13071.995), No.Rows = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 
5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 
22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 
38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 
54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 
70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 
86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 
101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 
114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 
127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 
140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 
153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 
166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 
179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 
192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 
205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 
218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 
231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 
244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 256, 
257, 258, 259, 260, 261, 262, 263, 264, 265, 266, 267, 268, 269, 
270, 271, 272, 273, 274, 275, 276, 277, 278, 279, 280, 281, 282, 
283, 284, 285, 286, 287, 288, 289, 290, 291, 292, 293, 294, 295, 
296, 297, 298, 299, 300)), row.names = c(NA, 300L), class = "data.frame") class = 
"data.frame")
```

I find the peaks and valleys of the data using:

```
library(quantmod)
max <- findPeaks(try$Actuator.Force)
min <- findValleys(try$Actuator.Force)
```

The result is the row.number of the `try` data.frame corresponding to the peaks and valleys. What I want is a vector of the `Actuator.Force` peak values corresponding to the row.numbers that the `findPeaks` and `findValleys` function find.

Answer (score 1):

If the min and max values are the row index of try data frame, you can get a subset of try:

```
> try[min, ]
    Actuator.Force No.Rows
5        -404.0766       5
97      -5043.0415      97
193    -14822.2040     193
> try[max, ]
    Actuator.Force No.Rows
3        -402.7260       3
7        -407.5543       7
133      4826.3135     133
253      4815.9038     253
```

If you want to get only the Actuator.Force values for max and min row index:

```
> try[min, "Actuator.Force"]
[1]   -404.0766  -5043.0415 -14822.2040
> try[max, "Actuator.Force"]
[1] -402.7260 -407.5543 4826.3135 4815.9038
```